The background of the Flickity button is not removed
I'm html, css, javascript Beginner.
I want to use Flickity for the slide page.
I want to remove the round background of the Flickity button(Arrow).
But even if I refer to the background removal code in flickity, it doesn't apply on my page..
What's the problem?

html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>My Calendar</h3>
    <!-- Flickity HTML init -->
    <div class="carousel" data-flickity>
        <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
        <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
        <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
        <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
        <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.carousel {
    background: #EEE;
  }
  
  .carousel-cell {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #8C8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    counter-increment: gallery-cell;
  }
  
  /* cell number */
  .carousel-cell:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    content: counter(gallery-cell);
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
  }

/* big buttons, no circle */
.flickity-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: transparent;
}


Which round background you want to remove, I have not found any round background.

Use !important for your flickity-button class. It will work. !important is used for overwriting the previous css rule.
background: transparent !important;


Thank you, but do you know why my code doesn't apply?

Its because, you included Flickity.min.css CDN to your html. Basically .flickity-button class have inherit the styles from the included file.
In that file, .flickity-button class have the background. So you need to overwrite it, that is why we use !important.

However, flickity's documentation does not specifically specify the use of things like !important.
Isn't the CDN method I use a common method?
I think it's very inefficient to have to use !important every time.

Flickity's documentation wont specify "!important" as it is normal CSS syntax. Basically, if you have two or more CSS styles for a single element and if you want to overwrite it, you can use "!important".
